# How to extract the img title next to span as per the given HTML through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am making a web crawling for checking a kind of availability.
I want to check the title of the specific time. However, if the title is 'NO', there is no href, otherwise there is a href. Therefore, it's xpath depends on the title. The title name changes every time. So i can't check by xpath.

If I want to check the availability of 09:00~11:00, how can do that?

I tried to find by XPATH. However, since the XPATH changes as I told, I can't to check the specific time i want.

Thanks in advance.

Below is the HTML code.

```
<span class="rs">07:00~09:00</span><img src="../images/reservation_btn04.gif" title="NO"><br>
<span class="rs">09:00~11:00</span><img src="../images/reservation_btn04.gif" title="NO"><br>
<span class="rs">11:00~13:00</span><img src="../images/reservation_btn04.gif" title="NO"><br>
<span class="rs">13:00~15:00</span><a href="./reg_add.asp?regdate=2018-09-16&amp;ftime=4&amp;ftype=1&amp;fac=C"><img src="../images/reservation_btn03.gif" title="YES"></a><br>
<span class="rs">15:00~17:00</span><a href="./reg_add.asp?regdate=2018-09-16&amp;ftime=5&amp;ftype=1&amp;fac=C"><img src="../images/reservation_btn03.gif" title="YES"></a><br>
<span class="rs">17:00~19:00</span><a href="./reg_add.asp?regdate=2018-09-16&amp;ftime=6&amp;ftype=1&amp;fac=C"><img src="../images/reservation_btn03.gif" title="YES"></a><br>
<span class="rs">19:00~21:00</span><img src="../images/reservation_btn04.gif" title="NO"><br>
```

Comment: How did you try? Share your current code along with current/desired output

Comment: I tried to find by its xpath. However, the form of xpath is different depending on 'YES' or 'No'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to check the availability of any timespan e.g. **09:00~11:00** you can use the following solution:

- You can create a `function()` which will take an argument as the timespan and extract the *availability* as follows:

  ```
  def check_availability(myTimeSpan):
      print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='rs'][.='" + myTimeSpan + "']//following::img[1]").get_attribute("title"))
  ```
- Now you can call the *function* `check_availability()` with any timespan as follows:

  ```
  check_availability("09:00~11:00")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If the text `09:00~11:00` is fixed, you can locate the `img` element like this -

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='rs' and contains(text(),'09:00~11:00')]/following-sibling::img")
```

To check whether the `title` attribute of the element is "YES" -

```
if element.get_attribute("title") == 'YES':
    // do whatever you want
```

To get the `href` attribute of your required element-

```
source = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='rs' and contains(text(),'09:00~11:00')]/following-sibling::img[@title='YES']/preceding-sibling::a").get_attribute("href")
```

Comment: Thanks Mishra. The code works well! One more question. If there are many days contains 09:00~11:00, how can i check a specific day?

Comment: @hoesangchoi you have to find a unique locator for it maybe using known ancestor or sibling.

Comment: @ Shivam Mishra There is a problem. If I check img titles of 09:00~11:00, the later times of 11:00 are considered as sibling. Therefore, when i check 07:00~09:00, all are checked.

Comment: I solved it by adding [1] after img such as /following-sibling::img[1]